# Maximum and Minimum integer from array excluding NULL or ZERO values

Tags: php, arrays

I am using below php functions to get highest and lowest integer value from my array.

`min($output[$k])` AND `max($output[$k])`

Problem:
I want to get maximum and minimum integer values from that array excluding `ZERO`s and `NULL` values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php) to filter array:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$buffer   = array(null, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, null, 1);
$filtered = array_diff($buffer, array(null, 0));

$max = max($filtered);
$min = min($filtered);

var_dump($max, $min);
?>
```

Shows:

```
int(3)
int(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
max(array_filter($output[$k));
```