# concate exculding NULL variable

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation, explode

I have several variables, which i receives from upon entry in one of my form via multiple select options. Total 4 select options are available which user can select maximum all or else he can select minimum one.
Once user selects data is inserted in the DB and is successful. I have used concate to join all the variables (selected 4 variables)

```
$amenities=$amenities_a.','.$amenities_b.','.$amenities_c.','.$amenities_d;

output:Helmet,Cherry,fruits,water
```

Problem: I want to upload this data whatever the user selected with variables COMMA separating each variable which is working fine. But incase of user do not select any of the option it generated `NULL` variable and it reflects as below (example where only one and first select option is selected ).

For one (first) selected option:

```
output shows: Helmet,,,
output required: Helmet
```

I want to make sure that incase respective variable is `NULL` it should not reflect in there with no commas. Will it be okay to try explode here.

Comment: you should check of other variable isset or not before merging them into one variable.

Comment: -1 from me because this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

Comment: There is also an analogy to a question you asked earlier yourself: [Maximum and Minimum integer from array excluding NULL or ZERO values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161214/maximum-and-minimum-integer-from-array-excluding-null-or-zero-values) - I'm just commenting this, because if you better understand PHP data types, like for what an array is for and that functions exist for arrays in a library that ships with PHP, you should be able to solve such trivial issues you ask about in quite lengthy questions more directly. Just saying, we're all here to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$amenities=  preg_replace("/,+/", ",", $amenities);
```

Comment: Hi Amir, That's what i required!! Thanks!! :)

Comment: What would happen if $amenities contains 3 or 4 sub_$amenities and you preg_replace the commas? in your database you will get **HelmetCherryfruitswater** instead of **Helmet,Cherry,fruits,water**?

Comment: $amenities= rtrim($amenities, ',');     use this to eliminate last comma!!

Comment: @sidd, Yes, you right,actually i thought, you need to last comma ;)

Answer (score 0):

do it with the help of conditional statement and isset function like:

```
$amenities=$amenities_a
if(isset($amenities_b){
  $amenities= $amenities. ' , '. $amenities_b
}
```

and etc..