# Get minimum value from an array that contains null values

Tags: php, arrays

How to get minimum value from an array containing some null values in PHP. I have an array like this

```
array(10,20,null,60)
```

As this array contains null so php `min` function giving 0 as minimum value, but I need for example 10 as minimum. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Filter the array before using `min()`: `$smallest = min(array_filter($array, function ($v) { return !is_null($v); }));`

Comment: `array_filter` will also remove zeroes I think

Comment: Actually, it will remove anything evaluating to `false`, so http://php.net/manual/ro/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum and Minimum integer from array excluding NULL or ZERO values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161214/maximum-and-minimum-integer-from-array-excluding-null-or-zero-values)

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv, You are correct.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`array_diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to exclude `null` values and after this process use [`min()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php):

```
$r = array_diff(array(10, 20, null, 60), array(null));
min($r);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `array_filter()` as a wrapper with `strlen` as call-back..

```
echo min(array_filter($arr,'strlen'));
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/148698)</kbd>

Comment: my answer is almost same so i have deleted mine :)

Comment: @AwladLiton, Nope not same, actually, yours would even filter zeroes. Hey btw I am not the downvoter.

Comment: The accusation that this answer will remove zero values is not true.  This answer will remove all values that have zero-length after being converted to a string -- e.g. `false` and `null`.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/EsqRp

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
    function min($array){
         $min = 1000;//max value you expect
       for($i=0; $i<sizeof($array); $i++){

            if($array[$i] < $min && $array[$i] != null)
                   $min = $array[$i];

       }
       return $min;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your array 'could' contain all NULL values, the previously mentioned methods will not work. The simplest solution I have come up with is:

```
min(array_replace([$defaultValue], array_filter($array)));
```

1. The array_filter will sort out any NULL values
2. The array replace will override your default value if array_filter returns an array containing at least one value

This will allow the minimum value to be returned from the original array, unless all values are NULL in which the default value will return

Comment: The default behavior of `array_filter()` destroys zeros. https://3v4l.org/FiWb0

Comment: @mickmackusa is right. Should be "array_filter($array, 'is_numeric')".